# $(document).ready not working in ajax page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm loading my page contents dynamically with ajax and I want to load certain .js files with a function. The .js file loads fine, but only before the next page has been loaded via ajax.

For example: from homepage to biography page:
1st loads the .js file 
2nd: loads the biography page (via ajax)

It looks like that the ajax page is always on state document ready. So it wil trigger immediately the .js file, before it loads the content of the biography page via ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".element").click(function() {
    jQuery.getScript("http://example.com/js/file.js");  
  });           
});
```

I've manage to solve this problem temporary with a timeout, so that the .js file will load after 5 seconds, so after the page biography has been loaded.

```
$(".element").click(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    jQuery.getScript("http://example.com/js/file.js");
  }, 5000);
});
```

How can I change the function so that it will load the .js file as soon as the biography page has been loaded (or any other page), instead of a timeout.

EDIT1:

I've added the ajax call here: 
http://jsbin.com/ediFUca

Comment: I am failing to understand what your process is. Are you calling `getScript()`, then from `file.js` are you loading the 2nd page?

Comment: where is the ajax call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX allows you to specify a *callback*: a function to call when the request is finished.

Put your scripts/functions in the callback and it will execute when your seconds page has completed loading, effectively solving your problem:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "test.html"
}).done(function() {
   //do things in here that should be done after the AJAX call e.g:
   jQuery.getScript("http://example.com/js/file.js");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the example. Although I would like to have a more generic solution. As this is not great in wordpress posts. Say I want to load a js file in every post I open, then this example won't suit. But it's a good start, thanks for you example, +1

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned in first line that **you are loading contend dynamically** so your predefined click handler will not fired for content that are added later.

So you need to use event delegation.

use `jQuery.on();` for that.

**Sample**

```
jQuery(document).on('click',".element",function()
{
    jQuery.getScript("http://example.com/js/file.js");
});
```

Comment: sorry, js file doesn't execute with your example